# How to pass an object to mutation in typescript 3.0

Tags: typescript, graphql

I have an object `input` and want to pass it to `mutation`:

```
export enum RatingType {
  GENERAL = 'GENERAL',
  ADULT = 'ADULT',
}
const input = {
  id: '123456789',
  name: 'yourname',
  ratingType: RatingType.ADULT
}
```

How to pass `input` into `mutation` like this:

```
mutation = `mutation updateUser{
  user: {
     id: "1234567890",
     name: "yourname",
     ratingType: ADULT,
  }
}`
```

i tried as below

```
import {request} from 'graphql-request';
const mutation = `mutation updateUser{
  user: {
     ${JSON.stringify(input)}
  }
}`
const response = await request('http://localhost:3002/graphql', mutation);
```

but `mutation` doesn't recognize:

`"id"` must be `id`

`"name"` must be `name`

`"ratingType"` must be `ratingType`

`'123456789'` must be `"123456789"`

`'yourname'` must be `"yourname"`

`'ADULT'` must be `ADULT`

Please give me advice

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, GraphQL is not JSON. So it makes no sense to use JSON.stringify here.
In GraphQL you can use variables for your arguments to solve your problem. Then you can provide your variables in JSON format.

Without knowing what library you are using I'm assuming that you communicate with your graphql server without any graphql library. I'm assuming that you use something similar to `fetch`.

I guess you have something like UpdateUserInput as a graphql type for your input argument.
So to use variables you need to rewrite your mutation like the following:

```
mutation UpdateUser($input: UpdateUserInput) {
  updateUser(user: $user) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

Then you can provide your variables like this:

```
input: JSON.stringify(input)
```

So the full `fetch` call will look something like this

```
const data = {
  query: `
    mutation ($input: UpdateUserInput) {
      updateUser(user: $user) {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  `,
  variables: {
    user: input
  }
};
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(data),
});
```

But it is hard to say how to implement it correctly without knowing your GraphQL client library. Maybe you'll want to have a look at ApolloClient.

Also please keep in mind that I didn't test this code, so there might be some minor errors.